# Help! I purged every compiz package

Tags: compiz

I just did something not very clever, I ran by mistake:

```
sudo apt purge compiz*
```

But what I really meant to do was:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall compiz*
```

Now I don't have a window manager, I can't type anything because my keyboard stopped working and I can only use the mouse.

How can I undo all this mess?

I happen to have a Live USB image in one of my usb flash drives. Can I use it to solve this?

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Xenial Xerus.

I need help.

Comment: try booting up, at login screen go to tty3 (ctrl+alt+F3). Login in there & see if you can `sudo apt install compiz unity` if so then after reboot.

Comment: @doug That worked perfectly! I am really grateful for your help. Thank you.

Comment: If you had happened to have had `compiz-plugins` or `compizconfig-settings-manager` installed before you'll also need to re-install them, otherwise you should be back to where you were.

Comment: @doug Please post an answer and ping me so I can up-vote. Thank you.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I will definitely up-vote it too.